# Access File in Webapp Folder Without Using Context

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, io, relative-path

I'm trying to get access to a .jsp file in my Maven project. The filepath for this folder is as follows:

```
projectMainFolder ▸ ⁨src⁩ ▸ ⁨main⁩ ▸ ⁨webapp⁩ ▸ ⁨px⁩ ▸ ⁨basefolder⁩ 
▸ ⁨domain ▸ ⁨subdomain ▸ ⁨oco ▸ file.jsp
```

The file I'm trying to access it from is in the following filepath:

```
⁨projectMainFolder ▸ ⁨src⁩ ▸ ⁨main⁩ ▸ ⁨java⁩ ▸ ⁨com⁩ ▸ ⁨websiteName 
▸ ⁨sameNameAsProjectMainFolder ▸ ⁨helper⁩ ▸ file.java
```

I've attempted using `getServletContext(/src/.../oco/file.jsp).getResourceAsStream()` and other methods that use the servlet context, but they always wind up null. Am I using the wrong parent directory? I've tried starting from src, webapp, main, and from px. (Naturally that elipses is not what I actually pass in but just a placeholder for all the in-between folders.)

Right now, I just want to store the file like so:

```
File resource = new File(/src/.../oco/file.jsp);
```

but resource always comes up as empty.

EDIT:

If I give the project the exact path to the file (starting from the /Users/ directory) it works, but of course I intend on deploying this as a webapp so this is not an option, but it at least proves that the only issue is how I'm setting up the filepath.

Comment: your directory is all screwed up. In your kind of project root is in webapp. Put your jsp files in the webapp folder.  Then you can just do: `File resource = new File(file.jsp); ` - you will probably need to restart and clean project+ server after moving the files and modifying web.xml

Answer (score 1):

`webapp` directory is the root of the public resoures, try accessing `⁨/px⁩/⁨basefolder⁩/domain/subdomain/oco/file.jsp`